# What are the best questionnaires to measure stress before and after use of VR application?

Tags: stress

I am making a VR application for my master thesis where people enter a virtual "rage room". I want to check if enhancing VR with the use of haptic feedback, gloves in this case, helps to reduce stress. I am looking for one or more questionnaires to measure stress before and after the test to evaluate the use of the application. What are the best questionnaires to use? The test subjects will be between 16 and 60 years old.

Comment: Welcome. Can't you use pupillometry during testing? A fancy way is collecting blood samples and check for cortisol. Questionnaires are not really my cup of tea. Searching for 'stress inventory' on Google yields many hits though, e.g. Holmes- Rahe Stress Inventory